# hql on subclass property

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism, hql

I have a class A and sub-classes B and C which have different properties.
How can I do something like:
a from A a where ( a.class = B and a.specific-property-of-b = "y") or (a.class = C and a.specific-property-of-c ="z")

Is it possible to get hibernate understand that when it's an instance of a certain class then it can access the specific properties of it or is it impossible to do something like that and I have to do:

a from A a where a.id in (select b.id from B b where b.specific-property-of-b = "y")
 or a.id in (select c.id from C c where c.specific-property-of-c = "z")

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You do it as you suggested:

```
select a from A a 
where (a.class = B and a.specificPropertyOfB = 'y')
or (a.class = C and a.specificPropertyOfC = 'z')
```

The only thing that won't work correctly (in my experience) is if you define two persistent fields with the same name in both subclasses.

Comment: When I try this way I get an error because hibernate looks for specificPropertyOfB in C. So right now I'm doing the second way but I don't think it's optimum.

Comment: It is exactly my case... I have two subclasses with the same attribute name. In the superclass there is an abstract method with that name. Each subclass implements this attribute in a particular way, but uses the same name. There is a solution for that after all those years?